# php + mysql (join?)

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe this way it will make more sense.

MySQL "table"

Code:

```
id1 | id2
 1  |  2
 1  |  3
 2  |  4
 2  |  3
 3  |  4
 3  |  5
```

WHERE `id1 = 1`, this id is connected to `2` and `3`: `1->2`, `1->3`

What I want to do is output the IDs of `2` and `3` which are NOT connected to `1`, which in this particular case would be `4` and `5`.

- `2->4` (1 is NOT connected to 4 = OK)
- `2->3` (1 is connected to 3 = NOT OK)
- `3->4` (1 is NOT connected to 4 = OK) ...but it should **NOT be displayed twice**, only because 2 and 3 are connected to 4!!
- `3->5` (1 is NOT connected to 5 = OK)

The only thing I could come up with would looks similar to the OHO code below, but I'd want to do all this within just one simple MySQL query, if possible (i.e. JOIN?):

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT id2 FROM table WHERE id1 = 1");
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
    $c = mysql_query("SELECT id2 FROM table WHERE id1 = $b[id2]");
    while($d = mysql_fetch_assoc($c))
    {
        $e = mysql_query("SELECT id2 FROM table WHERE id1 = 1 AND id2 = $d[id2]");
        $f = mysql_fetch_assoc($e);
        if(!$f['id2'])
        {
            echo $f['id2'];
        }
    }
}
```

**note:** One problem with the PHP code above is it would output 4 twice, because 2 and 3 are both connected to 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
select distinct a.id2
from myTable a
join (select id1, id2 from myTable where id1 = 1) b on a.id1 = b.id2
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from myTable where id1 = b.id1)
```

Comment: yes, i just deleted the other post, because people had a hard time trying to understand where i wanted to go. thank you, again. i already tried yours, but i wanted to tell you that for some reason its not working properly, because it outputs 4, 3 and 5 but 1 is already connected to 3. and i guess it has something to do with "<>", but im not definitely sure.

Comment: i think its because 1->2, 1->3, and 2->3 ...and because 2 is also connected to 3, it also outputs 3 (even tho 1 is already connected to 3). god, this is really giving me a headache.

Comment: ok.. i updated the answer with a NOT EXISTS sub query.. try that one out?

Answer (score 0):

What about `SELECT DISTINCT id2 FROM table WHERE id1 != 1`?

Comment: Forget that, this will give you all id2's that are linked at least once to an id1 that is not equal to 1. You'll need a subquery of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your problem properly, but do you want something like this?

```
select
  distinct a.id2
from
  myTable a
where
  a.id2 not in (select id2 from myTable where id1 = 1);
```